# Getting an issue to implement load more feature using node mongo express react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to implement load more feature in my react application. And for that I am creating an endpoint to implement load more. So, whenever app load it is fetching initial 5 data but unable to fetch next 5 data after clicking on load more button from UI.

Here is controller for that

```
export const loadMoreBlogs = async (req, res) => {
  const { skip } = req.body;
  try {
    const limit = 5;
    const blogs = await BlogModel.find().skip(skip).limit(limit);
    res.status(200).json(blogs);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

React component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loadMoreBlogs, setLoadedBlogs } from "../redux/features/blogSlice";

const Blogs = () => {
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const limit = 5;
  const { loadBlogs } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state.blog }));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadMoreBlogs(skip));
  }, [skip]);

  console.log("skip", skip);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    const skipTo = skip + limit;
    dispatch(loadMoreBlogs(skipTo));
    setSkip(skipTo);
    setLoadedBlogs(loadBlogs);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {loadBlogs?.map((item) => (
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleLoadMore}>Load More</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Blogs;
```

Comment: Can you explain `dispatch(loadMoreBlogs(skip));` line? Are you dispatching your controller function? Or is it an action creator that happened to have the same name as your controller?

Comment: It is an redux action which is making api request